# jurabib package - custom footnote indentation and footnote numbers

Tags: footnotes, citing, jurabib

So, our 'business management' professor wants me to do some modifications on my latex law paper.

I am a computer science engineer and it's my first time writing a law thesis. I cited with 'jurabib' as our professor wants us to cite with the footnote style I think is standard there. I didn't make any special modifications.

Here is what the footnotes on a site look like for example:
[image: image1]

My professor wants me to do the following modifications:

1. *A footnote citation that is too long and breaks onto the next line should have atleast the same indentation as the first line.*

For example the "8." should have AT LEAST the same indentation as the first line.

**Even better** would be reversed, so that the first line is on the left and the 2nd line is indented.

[image]

2. *Footnote numbers should begin with 1 on every page.*

Are those modifications possible and if yes, can you provide me some help? I admit that I checked the jurabib documentation, but probably not good enough.

Comment: The look of footnotes is not controlled by jurabib. You will have to make an compilable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ad 1:**

You can use

```
\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
```

to obtain what you want.

EDIT:

**ad 2:**
As figured out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701605/how-to-restart-footnote-numbering-every-page) you can use

```
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}
```

Comment: found that just by googling "align footnotes latex" and "restart footnote numbering each page latex"